# Links are not working on UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

In my application, I am using UIWebview to display some url say "Google". The problem is that, it is displaying the web page correctly but the links present on that page are not working.

Say if on Google page I click on map or gmail, then nothing happens. I know, I am missing some minor things, still need help from you.

Comment: show your code then only i can see what you missed..

Answer (score 11):

Check in Interface Builder your .xib with `UIWebView`, in Attributes Inspector (4th tab of the right panel) in section `Web View` `Detection Links` checkbox. **It must be checked on in order to make links work.**

Answer (score 2):

You also want to make sure that "User interactions Enabled" (in the View section of the attributes tab) is checked.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your link is constructed exactly like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

It should just "work".

Comment: OP is asking for a UIWebview problem on SWIFT. Not HTML

Comment: @Olufsen Actually, UIWebView is now deprecated.